# Tooltip constructed with container do not display text

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I've built a winform (C# .Net 4) application with a radio button.
When the form load, the program run the following code:

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip(this.components);
toolTip.SetToolTip(radioButton1, "tooltip text");
```

When I execute the program and hover the radio button with mouse cursor, the tooltip text is not displayed.

If I use the empty constructor, so the tooltip won't have any container, the text will appeare.

From the [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) about this class: *"ToolTips are not displayed when their container is inactive."*

Can this be the reason for not displaying im my case?
What does it mean for a container to be inactive, and how can active it?

Comment: Which place of calling this code? (ctor, Form_Load, etc)

Comment: Using IContainer ctor is way to organize a lifecycle of controls. I think Inactive means that Dispose method was called. But is is not your case.

Comment: Just to be sure: this.components has a value, right? Someting like `this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();`

Comment: yes. this is its value. it is the default added by the designer.

Comment: What happens when you add a tooltip via the designer and then set the controls tooltip text? Does it work then?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it led me to find the solution: The problem was that I've added the initialization of the 'components' field myself and it was override by the designer each time I changed something in the UI.

this cause my code to pass 'null' as argument to the ToolTip constructor, which disabled the tooltip.